# Showing results of model estimated with gsynth in model summary

Tags: r, modelsummary

I have estimated the following model in `R` using `gsynth`:

```
library(gsynth)

gsynth(
 m2 <- Y ~ D + X_1 + X_2,
  data = data,
  index = c("id", "time"),
  se = TRUE,
  cl = "id",
  inference = "parametric",
  CV = TRUE,
  force = "two-way",
  parallel = TRUE,
  min.T0 = 8,
  nboots = 1000,
  seed = 06511
)
```

I would like to put the stored estimates as a second column in a nice `modelsummary` table, showing the number of observations and the number of treated and control units. I was able to extract the info I need as follows but then I do not know how to put them in a table:

```
m2$est.avg
m2$N
m2$Ntr
m2$Nco
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are detailed instructions on how to add new kinds of models here: https://modelsummary.com/articles/modelsummary.html#new-models-and-custom-statistics